# MongoDB: $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use `$elemMatch` to find an object in an array. I imported the following data into a collection named `trails`:

```
{ "Copper" : [
        {"name" : "Spaulding Bowl", "level" : "Extreme Terain", "location" : "East Side"},
        {"name" : "Resolution Bowl", "level" : "Double Black", "location" : "East Side"},
        {"name" : "Black Bear Glade", "level" : "Double Black", "location" : "East Side"},
        {"name" : "Free Fall Glade", "level" : "Double Black", "location" : "East Side"}
 ]
}
```

I'm using the syntax from the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to make the following query:

```
db.trails.find( { "Copper": { $elemMatch: { "name" : "Spaulding Bowl" } }  } )
```

I have also tried formating it without quotations around the keys:

```
db.trails.find( { Copper: { $elemMatch: { name : "Spaulding Bowl" } }  } )
```

Instead of returning just one matching element, both return the entire array of objects. Is there a syntax error I'm missing? All tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[$elemmatch(query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)*** returns all rows in a array when there is atleast one row matching the query criteria.

***[$elemMatch(projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)*** returns only the first row of all the matching rows when used as projection.

You don't need elemMatch for your case as it is only single criteria.

```
db.trails.find({"Copper.name": { "Spaulding Bowl" } })
```

Try as below which uses the elemMatch projection variation.

```
db.trails.find({}, {"Copper": { $elemMatch: { "name" : "Spaulding Bowl" } }  } )
```

Comment: If I could ask one more question, how would I convert this to a mongoose query? I keep getting syntax errors.